# object has no attribute 'get_notification_display'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display human readable label of choicefield.

```
def reminder(request, pk=None):
    reminder = get_object_or_404(Reminder, pk=pk)
    print(reminder.id)  # printing correct value
    print(reminder.get_notification_display())
    return render(request, 'reminder.html', {'reminder': reminder, 'title': 'Reminder'})
```

But it throws this error :

```
AttributeError: 'Reminder' object has no attribute 'get_notification_display'
```

Here is the model:

```
class Reminder(models.Model):
    provider_type = (
        ('Em', 'Email'),
        ('Sm', 'SMS'),
        ('De', 'Desktop'),
        ('Mo', 'Mobile'),
    )
    notification = ArrayField(models.CharField(choices=provider_type, max_length=2, default='Em'))
```

Here's the documentation on [`get_FOO_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) - what am I missing?

Comment: Why should your object have this method?

Comment: check this doc  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) says

> For every field that has choices set, the object will have a get_FOO_display() method

but you don't have any [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) set for `notification`. In other words, you need a `NOTIFICATION_CHOICES` iterable of lenght two iterables in your class.

Answer (score 1):

```
 notification = models.CharField(choices=provider_type, max_length=2, default='Em')
```

remove the arrayfield as it is not allowing you to create and iterate one